# how to customize xcode server bot mail notification?

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration

[[image: mail notification from bot after ci]]

The style is not beautiful, How can i custom the mail title or mail content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a customize trigger to send mail notification, we can get [Xcode Server Environment Variable](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/EnvironmentVariableReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013292-CH14-SW1) to fill the custom content in mail.